# Prove that $f(x) = (\sin x, \cos x)$ defined from $\mathbb R$ to the unit circle is onto

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do you prove that the function $f: [0,2\pi$) $\rightarrow S^1$ such that $f(x) = (\sin x, \cos x)$, where $S^1$ is the unit circle, is onto?

I was thinking considering two variables a and b in the range of f(x) and stating that f(arcsin(a)) and f(arccos(b)) produce x, but that only works for the x and y coordinates one at a time, not simultaneously. Help?

Comment: $f$ is not a real-valued function.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net so?

Comment: So, your question needs to be reworked to make sense.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Okay so suppose f(x) describes the points from [0,2$\pi$) $\rightarrow$ the points on the unit circle. Better?

Comment: The fucntion you have given is from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. It is also most definitely _not_ onto

Comment: The range $[0,1)$ does not cover the entire unit circle. The range which does that is $[0,2\pi)$

Comment: In which case it is onto

Comment: So are you saying there is no function from (0, $2\pi$] $\rightarrow$ the points on the unit circle?

Comment: okay, @ASKASK then how do you prove it's onto?

Comment: Well then it all depends on how you define "the points on the unit circle". One standard definition is the set of all points of the form $(\sin(x),\cos(x))$, in which case, the fact that it is onto follows quite immediately

Comment: But how would you formally prove that?

Comment: Take $(a,b)$ to be on the unit circle. You suggested taking $f(\arccos(a))$ or $f(\arcsin(b))$. In fact these should both work. The trick is figuring out $\sin(\arccos(a))$ or $\cos(\arcsin(a))$, but drawing a unit circle should help you there. (Also, you have to be careful about which quadrant $(a,b)$ is in and which values $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$ take on, but that's a technicality.)

Comment: @kccu should you try both arccos(a) and arcsin(b)? Why would that work b/c arccos(a) $\neq$ arcsin(b).

Comment: In fact $\arccos(a)=\arcsin(b)$ if $(a,b)$ is on the unit circle (and again you're careful about which quadrant it's in). Try an example, like $\arccos(4/5)$ and $\arcsin(3/5)$. Again, drawing the unit circle and labeling the point $(a,b)$ will help you see why this is the case.

Comment: @kccu oh, if you try arccos(a) as the input for the function, so it result in the point (a,a)?

Comment: @Raton No, it results in the point $(\cos(\arccos(a)),\sin(\arccos(a)))$, which (if you draw a unit circle) you will see is equal to $(a,\sqrt{1-a^2})$. You would like it to be the point $(a,b)$ on the unit circle. But what is $b$ in terms of $a$ if $(a,b)$ is on the unit circle?

Comment: @kccu Thanks so much! You're a great teacher. So basically b/c every point on the unit circle can be described by ($\pm\sqrt{1-b^2}, \pm\sqrt{1-a^2})$, then our onto proof works. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't much more to this then you expect. Consider some arbitrary point in the codomain: $(\sin(a),\cos(a))$. By the definition of onto, all you have to do is show that there is some point in the domain $[0,2\pi)$ such that $f(x)=(\sin(a),\cos(a))$. Can you see how to take it from here?

Comment: Thanks man, good solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.**

The function $$
\begin{array}{l|rcl}
f : & [0,\pi] & \longrightarrow & [-1,1]\\
    & x & \longmapsto & \cos x\end{array}$$ is onto.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Let $(y_{1},y_{2}) \in S^{1}$; let $r:= \sqrt{y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2}}$. Then there is some $x \in [0, 2\pi[$ such that $x$ is the angle made by the vector $(y_{1},y_{2})$ with the horizontal axis and $y_{1} = r\cos x$ and $y_{2} = r\sin x$; but this shows that $f$ is surjective (onto).

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the most basic facts of analysis. If you assume the high school definition of $\cos$ and $\sin$, together with their continuity, ranges, etc., it is of course obvious, as declared in the accepted answer.

But if you start with an analytical definition of the trigonometric functions, say in terms of the exponential function,  of power series, or of ODE's, a full proof requires about two pages of work. You can find such a proof in the section *The trigonometric functions*, Chapter 8 of Baby Rudin.